# Где хранить свои сервисы (классы) в Laravel (7.x)?

Tags: php, laravel

Начал постигать дзен в Laravel, и наткнулся на на проблему хранения собственных классов.

То-есть нам дали `сервис-провайдеры`, чтобы подключать сервисы (классы) к `сервис-контейнеру` (глобальному объекту `App`). Но где их правильно хранить, с точки зрения архитектуры Laravel?

Comment: А это где вам удобнее, в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers) нет конкретного места по этому вопросу. Я, к примеру, храню либо в Services, либо в Connectors, в зависимости от типа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чаще всего встречал в App/Services, где и сам предпочитаю их создавать.